# How do I get my seagate hard drive to show up in SeaTools using an USB to SATA adaptor?

Tags: external-hard-drive, sata, usb-to-sata

```
Application Being Used: SeaTools For Windows
Hard Drive Model: ST320005 42AS
Interface: USB-To-SATA Adaptor
```

I keep running into an issue when trying to use SeaTools from Seagate.  I have a USB to SATA adaptor that I have hooked up to my 3½ inch Seagate SATA drive (1TB).  The drive shows up just fine in Windows Explorer and also shows up just fine in Windows Disk Management.  I can run tools on it, add files to the drive etc...

When I run SeaTools only my boot drive (C:) shows up...  Ideas?

---

**UPDATE**

I ended up going a different route.  After spending hours trying to get the USB-To-SATA drive to show up in SeaTools For Windows app, I just decided to use a different machine (because I didn't want to shutdown/restart my development machine).  On the other machine I still could not get it to work so I just grabbed a copy of SeaTools For DOS (what a pain Seagate's site is to get it) then made a bootable thumb drive and plugged the SATA drive straight to the motherboard as an internal hard drive.

Comment: Are you using Seatools for Windows or Seatools from a bootable DOS disk?

Comment: Sorry about that, I thought I said that in my question but I totally skipped over that fact!  Question updated.  Thanks!